# how to put an image in center above another image in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, layout

I want to create a layout like this:

[image]

I have 3 different images: the background, the white square and the V sign.

How can I position them as in the photo, if I want the box to move from side to side

and the V sign to fade in\out when onClick is triggered.

I have tried:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/off_background">


             <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:src="@drawable/handle"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/switch_v"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/switch_v"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

which gives me the order correctly, but not posed correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `layout_align` for this issue. I have tested it for your example and it worked correctly.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:background="@drawable/off_background" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/handle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/handle" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/switch_v"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/handle"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/handle"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/handle"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/handle"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/switch_v" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: isn't there a simpler way than aligning to all directions? what's the difference between alignTop\Right\ect.. and    `android:layout_gravity="center"` ?

Comment: For this example because of using `RelativeLayout` the best way is alignTop\Right\etc. `android:layout_gravity="center"` can use when you have `fill_parent` in your `layout_width` and `layout_height`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable for the the white square and the V sign:

white_square_and_V_sign.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/handle"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/switch_v"/>
    </item>  
</layer-list>
```

Create a drawable for the the white square:

white_square.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/handle"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Create a Selector:

mySelector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/white_square"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/white_square_and_V_sign" />
</selector>
```

Use it in your layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/off_background" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/mySelector"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it's not good for me, as I need the V sign to fade out separately from the white box.